# How to make Python 3.9 run command prompt windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

"python --version
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases."

This is what I get trying to make sure it works (clearly it doesn't). I'm quite a rookie with all this. I started cause I wanted to run some script on bluestacks, so I needed Python and ADB added both PATH. The problem comes here.... It is indeed added to Path:

`C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Sierra\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\platform-tools;C:\Users\Sierra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39;C:\Users\Sierra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib;`

This is PATHEXT: `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`

This is PYTHONPATH (I made it since I saw someone saying it would fix it):

`C:\Users\Sierra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39;C:\Users\Sierra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib;C:\Users\Sierra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include;C:\Users\Sierra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLS;C:\Users\Sierra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts;C:\Users\Sierra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages`

Weird enough the fact that ADB works fine:

`C:\Users\Sierra>adb --version Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 Version 30.0.5-6877874 Installed as C:\platform-tools\adb.exe`

Since I did the same in both cases, I can't get why it's not working. Maybe I did something wrong with the Python version I downloaded? Weird thing too, since I also have stilled version 3.8

Also, the script I need says "Python 3.7.X installed and added to PATH." I guessed 3.9 would work, since it's the newest

I apoloogize cause my English. I'm not native speaker, so I could have messed up somewhere. Many thanks!!
Forgot to tell, I use Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

When you run the setup exe for python a list of tiny boxes should pop up and one will say add PATH to python? If you click yes it will add PATH to python which seems like your issue I think? If you have multiple versions of python installed that could cause a issue type python in cmd if it has a error then you didn't install python properly. Double check you have all the required modules installed if that doesn't work then I'm lost. Anyways here's the code to open cmd.

> import os

> os.system("cmd")

Comment: When I run the setup I get add to the enviromental variables, but..... I just added py launcher while reinstalling and it still doesn't work using 'python' command, but works fine using 'py'... Weird.... I need to check if I can use 'py' for everything instead of python